# New to MVC-How to use Solr SEarch result(json response) in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, solr

I am new to MVC architecture, have just started learning it, but I have to actually make a page in MVC which displays result returned by SOLR search. I don't have a clue as to how to start or proceed or what to do?

Comment: Have you looked at this example: http://solrsharp.codeplex.com/

Comment: Basically i m not having any idea as to what to write and where to write? I just have the SOLR Search URL which i have placed in my web.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Kane suggested in his comment, you will need to look at a [Solr Client](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/IntegratingSolr) to use in your MVC website in order to query and parse the response from Solr.

I am assuming you are talking ASP.NET MVC3 here, so I would recommend the use of [SolrNet](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet). Also, if you download the library, it comes with a fully functional ASP.NET MVC example that you should be able to use to help jump start your development efforts.

My company has implemented multiple projects based on SolrNet and we have been extremely pleased with it it.